# How to append backslash if pattern matches in javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have to check if a string contains some special character, and if it does, add a backslash to it.

```
var spChar=['%','^','!'];
```

If string is `"This contains % and ^ characters".`

I want to make it `"This contains \% and \^ characters".`

I dont want to loop through all the characters. Is there anyway i can achieve this by using regex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a regex like

```
"This contains % and ^ characters".replace(/([%^!])/g, '\\$1')
```

---

But if you are looking to [escape regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript), you can use a function like

```
if (!RegExp.escape) {
    RegExp.escape = function (s) {
        return s.replace(/[\-\[\]{}()*+?.,\\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&")
    };
}

//then
var newstring = RegExp.escape(mystring)
```

Comment: Inside `escape` function, isn't it `s.replace(...)` instead of `value.replace(...)`?